# Flutter possible to create a List of AnimationController?

Tags: list, animation, flutter, dart

Not sure why this doesn't work, it throws the error `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0`

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {

List<AnimationController> dataCtrl = List<AnimationController>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    dataCtrl = [];
    dataCtrl[0] = AnimationController(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
      vsync: this,
    );
  }
```

Comment: Your list is already empty, you need to add `AnimationController` to it before you can use any index on it.

Comment: I'm adding that in initstate am I not?

Comment: do - `dataCtrl.add(AnimationController(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400))`

Comment: @Hasen No you are not adding anything. Check out my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  // add some AnimationController object before using any index
  dataCtrl.add(AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 1)));

  // now it is Ok to use 0 index
  dataCtrl[0] = AnimationController(
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
    vsync: this,
  );
}
```

Comment: Ok I see. Or I guess just `dataCtrl.add(AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400)));` would be fine too?

Comment: Yes, you can also do that.